# UIKIT uk-button not working on js

Tags: uikit

Can you please enlighten me on how things work on this?

I have a modal which has a button that when clicked is should display alert.

I have here my view:

```
     <div style="margin-top: 200px;">
       <a href="#modal-testing" uk-toggle>Click Button</a>
     </div>

     <div id="modal-testing" uk-modal>
        <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
          <h2 class="uk-modal-title">For Testing</h2>

        <p class="uk-text-right">
             <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary" id="btn_update" type="button">Save</button>
        </p>
     </div>
```

And here is my js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn_update').click(function (e) {

    alert('testing');
    console.log('testing');

   });
 });
```

I know this is just a simple question. I apologize. Appreciate your help on this. Documentation of uikit for me is really not that helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try mo to :D

```
$(document).on('click','#btn_update',function(){
  alert('ampedo');
});
```